# GIN - Pass a constructor parameter to my ClientModule

Tags: gwt, guice, gwt-gin

I have a pretty simple GIN usage in my GWT project. I followed the Guice tutorial to set it up.

I want to bind an unchanging Long variable to an annotation in my AbstractGinModule subclass. The problem is that I do now know the value of the variable until runtime (onModuleLoad). I have the value before I create the Ginjector... I just don't know how to get it into my Client module.

I've seen answers that say I can pass a constructor parameter to my ClientModule... but I don't see where it gets constructed. It's just annotation wiring.

```
@GinModules(MyClientModule.class)
public interface MyGinjector extends Ginjector {
}

public class MyClientModule extends AbstractGinModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(named("MyConstant")).to(???);
    }

public class MyEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {

        long myValue = 123456L; 
        MyGinjector injector = GWT.create(MyGinjector.class);
}
```

So how can I get my value 123456L into the configure() method of MyClientModule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to *pass* values to GIN is to use *shared state*, i.e. some `static` variable/method that you can set on one side and access/call from your `GinModule`.

Comment: I selected this as the correct answer because it is the simplest and clearest answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the value of your variable at compile time, it's technically not a constant. Also, if memory serves, the module class is used at compile time, not run time, so this approach won't quite work.

Could you just initialize your variable when you have the value?

Comment: I am happy to use bind(Long.class).annotatedWith(...).to(???)
It doesn't need to be a constant, it just needs to be available in the injector.

Comment: @Ben, you're correct: Unlike with Guice, implementations of GinModule are used at _compile time_ to generate dependency-injecting code. Guice would allow you to bind a Key to a constant (i.e. primitive or String), but doing so would affect the Module at runtime, which is a non-starter for Gin in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you can follow could be:

```
@Singleton
public class MyConstants {
   private long myLong = null;

   public void setLong(long yourLong) {
     this.myLong = yourLong;
   }

   public long getLong() {
     return myLong;  
   }
}
```

And then in your EntryPoint get the class:

```
public class MyEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
      MyGinjector.INSTANCE.getApplication().execute();
    }

}
```

-

```
public interface AppInjectorGin extends Ginjector {

  @GinModules(MyClientModule.class)
  public interface MyGinjector extends AppInjectorGin{

    MyGinjector INSTANCE = GWT.create(MyGinjector.class);
    AppMain getApplication();
  }

  //Space for more Injectors if you need them :)
}
```

-

```
public class AppMain {
  @Inject MyConstants myConstants;

  public void execute() {
    long theLong = 12345L;
    myConstants.setLong(theLong);
    //And now in every single place of your app, if you do 
    //@Inject MyConstants you will have there the value of the long.
  }
}
```

There are two keys here:

- The annotation `@Singleton` on the class `MyConstants` (otherwise
  `GIN` will create a new instance always).
- The class `AppMain`, you
  need to do in that way otherwise the injection `@Inject MyConstants`
  would be null (if you try to access it in the `EntryPoint` directly).